# Why does authClient.createUser throw an error with an invalid email address?

Tags: firebase

The following code throws a javascript error, where `some_email` is an improperly formatted email address:

```
var authClient = new FirebaseAuthClient(some_firebase_ref);
authClient.createUser(some_email, some_password, function(error, user) {
    console.log(error, user);
});
```

It gives this in the console:

```
Error: FirebaseAuthClient.createUser failed: First argument must be a valid email address.
```

Is there a reason that the callback doesn't simply fire with the error param filled in, and no user data?  It seems like that's a good case for the error param to be used, and lets us not have to write our own email validation or try/catch blocks.

Comment: As you suggested, the error should be returned in the error parameter on the callback, not as a thrown exception.

This is a bug on our side - I'll submit a fix, and follow-up once that fix has been pushed live.

Comment: This should now be fixed, but please follow-up if you continue to see problems. Thanks!